# Any idea on how this git fetch can be optimized?

Tags: git

git fetch origin %Branch_SourcePath% --depth 100 --no-tags --progress --verbose --recurse-submodules 2>&1

The command above takes about 1 hour to complete which is too long. Using --depth 1 completes the fetch in under 4 minutes however I do need the commit information for at least the last 100 commits.

Majority of the time is spent on download/receiving objects.

> Receiving objects:  99% (764574/764593), 25.39 GiB | 13.32 MiB/s

Comment: Keep a "reference clone" locally.

Comment: `25 GiB` ? im serious what kind of project is this?

Comment: @Sysix it's a bit large for Git today but it's not really that big in the Grand Scheme. We get multi-terabyte disk drives for under $20/TB, so 25 GB is about $0.40. (https://diskprices.com/)

Comment: @torek, thanks for the suggestion however the fetch is happening on an Azure DevOps pipeline.  I don't think I'd be able to keep any clone locally on these pipeline machines. Also, the local clone would need to be updated way too frequently.

Comment: In that case, there may be very little you *can* do. 13 MiB/s is about 100 Mbit/s and this is probably your allotted line speed. You might investigate what's allowed for the network between wherever you're cloning *from* and the machines you're cloning *to*.

Comment: @torek While 25GB is cheap in terms of storage, it's large in terms of a Git repo, for exactly the kind of problem OP is facing here. Over my VPN, cloning large repos is hard and failure prone. I can blame my org, they don't provide good enough networks, but I just avoid large repos in the first place. If they could, OP should consider getting that repo modified to use Git LFS, or split it, and if they can't, I agree with your last comment, there may not be much they can do.

Comment: @joanis: I've felt that pain myself: for a long time, for various mostly-stupid reasons, I had a sub-500-kbit/s DSL line when everyone else had at least 4x that line rate. Fortunately the DSL itself wasn't also *flaky*, but it took me all day to download large DVD images for test-installs of our OS.

Answer (score 0):

#### option #1: sparse checkout

If you only need a subtree of the original directory tree, one thing you can try is the so-called [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout).

For example, lets say we are interested only in `/foo` subdirectory.

```sh
git clone --sparse --depth 10 --branch master https://github.com/Acme/helloworld
```

Change directory into the newly-cloned repository and enable sparse-checkout mechanism (to fetch parts of the subtree in steps of increasing depth):

```sh
cd helloworld
git sparse-checkout init --cone
```

Checkout a subtree, say at `/foo`:

```sh
git sparse-checkout set foo
```

#### option #2: filtering BLOBs

Another thing you can try is to filter BLOB objects (`--filter blob:none` in `git-clone` command).

Comment: Better, the OP should probably break his (26GB!) repo into smaller, more manageable "chunks"...

Comment: @paulsm4, yes of course! but i suppose that cannot be changed from the OP's side

Comment: A sparse checkout will still clone the full 25 GB. A partial clone (with `--filter`) won't, so that will save time. But a reference clone is usually the way to go. I cut down a 2 hour clone process to 30 seconds this way once.

Comment: @torek, but wont a sparse checkout save some time from decompressing files into the working directory?

Comment: A bit–but the OP that `--depth 1` was decently fast, so it's mostly cloning older objects that's taking the time, rather than checking out the latest-commit's objects.

Comment: @MichailAlexakis, you are correct I cannot make such drastic actions as breaking up the repo myself. I do need all files in the repo though.

Comment: @jyim89: the simple fact is that you probably *SHOULD* break up the repo.  Git is extremely scalable ... but it's designed to work primarily with *versions* of *text files*. I'm guessing (you haven't really told us) that your repo probably has *many versions* of a large # of large *binary* files.  If so, your organization should definitely consider alternative ways to "archive" them.  Something like Box, Google Drive, or AWS S3 perhaps.  Q: Is there any way you can discuss this with your team lead or management?